# Why can't I edit a site asset document?

Tags: document, edit

If I go here in SharePoint then I am looking at my site assets:

```
https:// ... /SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

At this location I can view a list of documents that the site has. I have full admin rights to the site and I am supposed to be able to do anything with the site.

If I hover over any of the documents in the list and click the drop down arrow that appears, I get lots of options, such as edit the properties, check it out, delete it, manage permissions, and so on.

I can do this for all the documents in the library **EXCEPT ONE** aspx page. For this document the only options I get are View Properties, Compliance Details, Alert me and Send to. And when I click on View Properties, the Edit Item option in the ribbon is grayed out.

This is the one document I need to modify and yet I can't, even as the admin.

It is not check out to anyone and is ready to be modified.

What can I do to be able to make changes to it?

Please help.

Comment: Did you try edit the from the SharePoint Designer?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti, no I did not. I can't open the site in Designer since out IT department locks down production sites. There should be a way to do this in the web interface.

Comment: I think files can`t be editable from the browser. But you can download the file and make changes and upload back. Do you have permissions to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if you have Full Control permissions to the site or to the library if the file does not inherit permissions from the site or library and if permissions of the file do not specify that you have Full Control. In a nutshell, you only have Read permissions to that file, either directly or as a member of a group.

Permissions in SharePoint can be a bit confusing. Only site collections administrator truly have Full Control to anything.

The solution is to ask IT or a site collection administrator to give you permissions to edit the file.